# How to use Kibana and elastichsearch [7.5.0] to track number of documents containing particular value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have an index which contains information about some objects. I want to display some of the information on my Kibana's dasboard. Lets assume an object looks as follows:

```
 {
  "_index": "obj",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "KwDPAHABfo5V345r4IYV",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "value_1": "some value",
    "value_2": "some_other value",
    "owner": "jason",
    "modified_date": "2020-02-01T12:53:08.210317+00:00",
    "created_date": "2020-02-01T12:53:08.243980+00:00"
   }
 }
```

I need to show (live) number of objects that has `owner: 'UNKNOWN'`. Thing is, that this value changes in time. Each change is a new document - they are not being updated. I need to track how many UNKNOWN owners currently I see. Updates (new documents) are being sent to elk in fixed intervals. 
When I try to set up a metric, it sometimes shows 0, during the window between one update and another - when there is no documents flowing into elk. How can I make Kibana display only last documents with `owner: 'UNKNOWN'`?

Comment: Have you had success with my suggested approach? Please give me some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make Kibana display only last documents with owner: 'UNKNOWN'?

You could set up a data table visualization for that as an alternative to the one-dimensional metric visualization.

This is how I personally would configure the data table:

- Set a filter with 'owner(.keyword) is UNKNOWN'.
- Use the metric 'Top Hit' on the field created_date (or @timestamp, thats up to you) instead of the count metric.
- Set the order to descending based on the timestamp field.
- Split the rows (Term Aggregations) for every field you want to display in the rows. This will create 'columns' in your table.
- Go to the options tab and enable count on the sum of all rows.
- Set an appropriate time interval, e.g. last 1 hour.

This will display all the relevant data of your documents that have the field owner equal to UNKNOWN. Also, you see the ingestion/creation date timestamp of these documents in a descending order. Furthermore, you see the number of documents that match (configured via the options tab as described above).

I hope I could help you.